# MultiGet on Percolator ids in Nest

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm using Nest to talk agains Elasticsearch, now I have the following problem.

I want to get percolators with their metadata, by doing a MultiGet on the percolator IDs on a specific Index.

The problem I have is within the following code

```
client.MultiGet(m=>m.GetMany<MyType>(percolatorIds))
```

How do I know what type to specify for MyType because the mapping inside Elasticsearch is the .percolator type? And how can I specify the index where I want to look for the ids?

Comment: I was able to get query, I don't know if it's enough metadata for you. Are you looking for something particular? Looks like there is no big support in ES for such requirement.

Comment: Have you tries just specifying 'object' as the type?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your support I found the way to do it.

I made a new POCO with the name `MatchingCriterium` and added the attribute `[ElasticType(Name = ".percolator")]` to it something like below.

```
[ElasticType(Name=".percolator")]
public class MatchingCriterium
{ 
   public string MetaData1 {get;set;}
   public string MetaData2 {get;set;}
   public int MetaData3 {get;set;}
}
```

And this fixed my problem

Comment: Can you add the `MultiGet` code you ended up using too? Even with this POCO I can't seem to read the response. Thanks!